# Magento 1.x Best way to get admin skin URL from frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, adminhtml

What is the best way of getting the URL path of the current admin skin theme directory.

I am aware of

```
Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->getSkinUrl();
```

Which will return the URL of the front-end skin theme directory. Is there an Adminhtml equivalent?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For admin skin url, you can use:

```
<?php echo Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseUrl(array('_area'=>'adminhtml')) ?>
```

This method can be found in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php`.

You can also pass other params via the array like `_package` and `_theme` if you want the url of certain package/theme.

Comment: Nice one bro, okay so you can pass a parameter,that's great!

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to get a secure skin URL:

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));
```

To get an insecure skin URL:

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');
```

Comment: Sorry bro, I'm looking for the skin URL of the admin from the front-end. If I used $this from front-end surely I'll get a front-end URL?

Answer (score 2):

Core Magento uses this in core code:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/image.gif');
```

Which calls:

```
public static function getDesign()
{
    return self::getSingleton('core/design_package');
}
```

They are both equivalent except that `$this` may not work in all contexts/cases so I would recommend using `Mage::getDesign()` to avoid having issues.

PHP 5.3 has some issues using `$this` in some contexts.

You should be able to use `Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package');` consistently as well.

Magento identifies which 'area' you're calling getDesign from so...

To evoke **adminhtml** or **frontend** areas and get their skin urls use:

```
$oDesign = Mage::getDesign()->setArea( 'adminhtml' );
$oDesign = Mage::getDesign()->setArea( 'frontend' );
var_dump( $oDesign );
$sUrl = $oDesign->getSkinUrl('images/image.gif');
var_dump( $sUrl );
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. What if you are in the front-end (when calling in a layout file for example) and wish to access the back-end URL? Using the above code would surely return the front-end path right?

Comment: I updated the answer on how to call admin from frontend and vice versa